# Difference between Linux Headers, Linux Images, and the Generic versions

Tags: kernel

I am curious to know the difference between the large number of linux kernel files that come when a kernel is installed, namely, the follows:

- linux-headers-x.x.x-x
- linux-headers-x.x.x-x-generic
- linux-image
- linux-image-x.x.x-x-generic

I would also like to whether there are similar files and the difference between those too.

**UPDATE:** I have seen the question below, but it does not seem to answer the question completely:

- [Why are there so many "linux-" kernel packages on my machine, and what do they all do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266772/why-are-there-so-many-linux-kernel-packages-on-my-machine-and-what-do-they-a?rq=1)

Comment: I am closing this question as the other question treats exactly the same contents, it just does not have a good answer. Upvote the other question and edit it if necessary.