# Why do most of my drivers not load after updating kernel to 3.13.0-36?

Tags: drivers, kernel, updates, keyboard

I recently upgraded my system with a new motherboard, and reinstalled Trusty to have an AMD64 system (old motherboard was 32-bit). Reinstallation (side-by-side), with 14.04.01 LTS went fine and new build was running well.

Then the Software Updater installed updates, including a new kernel (3.13.0-36-generic). On the next reboot I got a kernel panic. I tried a couple of times and found that the -36 kernel just wasn't working. Switching back to the original (3.13.0-32-generic) worked fine. I found that the -36 kernel was missing most of its ko files. Forcing a reinstall with apt allowed update-initramfs to succeed, and I tried another reboot.

This time, the -36 kernel booted, but left me with no network, no keyboard (USB), and no mouse (USB). Probably no sound as well.

Since then, I have tried uninstalling and purging the -36 kernel and reinstalling it and reupdating the ramfs and grub2 configuration. Still the same behavior: -32 works fine, -36 fails to load most drivers and leaves me at a login screen where I cannot log in.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: I just noticed that the initrd images under /boot are of radically different sizes - About 27MB for -32 and about 10MB for -36.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problema here, my server didn't start with USB and network. I saw that package "linux-generic-pae" was missing. System 32-bit need this package, I found this [Why are there so many "linux-" kernel packages on my machine, and what do they all do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266772/why-are-there-so-many-linux-kernel-packages-on-my-machine-and-what-do-they-a).

This solve for me:
apt-get install linux-generic-pae

Comment: It's unlikely that will fix the problem at hand as we know far too few about the state of OP's system. We do know however, that he doesn't use a x86 PAE kernel, but AMD64.